# Using placeholders

Tags: yaml, apache-camel, placeholder

I have route

```
from("direct:standardLetter")
            .toD("file://standardReceived?fileName=${header.filename}");
```

and I want to put my uris in YAML.
But I have a problem when I put

from("direct:standardLetter")
.toD("{{endpoints.writer-routes.out.standard-output-file.uri}}")

in YAML file like this

```
endpoints:
  writer-routes:
    out:
      standard-output-file:
        id: "standard-output-file"
        uri: "file://standardReceived?fileName=${header.filename}"
```

How to overcome this?

Comment: [Documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/using-propertyplaceholder.html) doesn't say anything about being able to use yaml files with property-placeholders. instead its all about using [.properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) files. Is this related to [yaml-dsl](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/others/yaml-dsl.html), [camel-k](https://camel.apache.org/camel-k/next/index.html) or something?

Comment: The problem is that springboot on startup wants to resolve the properties to inject them into the application. Remember properties/yaml values are needed to start the application. So they are resolved before the application runs. However the header.filename "property" is only available when camel is running, this value is a property of the exchange which only is available when the route runs. Thus it will not translate correctly as during startup there is no exchange as camel is not executing yet. You cannot refer to a runtime values from a properties/yaml  file like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you set the target filename into the header `filename`. Then you use it in the URI.

If you use the header name `CamelFileName` instead you can omit the `fileName` option from the URI because this is the **standard header name of Camel** and therefore used automatically if nothing else is overriding it.